# how to create 1 combined image from 4X4 imageView matrix

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am creating **"Jigsaw game"** for that i've divided single image into 4X4 matrix like

[image]

Now I have 16 different imageViews  I need to combine them into one single image and store in database. So is it possible to combine 4x4 matrix images into one image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, and it's fairly easy.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(fullSize);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

        UIImage *image = [self imageAtRow:i column:j];
        CGFloat imageSize = 40;
        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake (imageSize * i, imageSize * j, imageSize, imageSize);
        CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage);  

    }

}

UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

`result` will be an image of the full size you created (160x160 if its 4x4 with 40 size images)

**EDIT**

Use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fullSize, NO, 0.0);` to support retina displays

Comment: Is it adding the same image to each position? is it just adding the first image? have you checked that it's properly iterating over every image and that you are selecting the correct image every time? Is the rect calculated correctly for each image? I do this myself in my own project and it works fine

Comment: I have image array of length 16
so first 4 images placed in first row and so on.

Comment: but it display only first image don't know why??